# Apply CSS to Angular directives (custom or not) with native handle

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let say I have a Angular app with directives like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="cfd">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">    
      <!-- Header -->
      <div ui-view="header" class="row"></div>

      <div ui-view="main" class="row">
        <!-- Sidebar/Nav -->
        <div ui-view="sidebar" class="col-xs-3"></div>
        <!-- Content -->
        <div ui-view="content" class="col-xs-9"></div>
      </div> 

      <!-- Footer -->
      <div ui-view="footer" class="row"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I apply CSS to a directive using the Angular directive handle `ui-view` or any other custom directive, without adding an HTML ID handle.   SO for the "main" section, I dont want the following: `<div id="main" ui-view="main" class="row">`.

I have tried `.ui-view#main` and `ui-view#main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the angular directive ui-view as identifier in your CSS?

In your CSS file, you could potentially use

```
div[ui-view=main] {
    /* styles for main go here, duh! */
}
```

Seems to work in Chrome (http://plnkr.co/edit/r1fvheUs8S6AJHv4Dm59?p=preview)

If you want conditional styles, you should use

```
<div ng-class="{'className': 'angular condition'}"></div>
```